# Check Checkbox with ASP.NET Response.Write and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to check a check box from a button click event using Jquery but it's not working. What is missing from my code?  Here is my html:

```
<input name="OldForm" id="OldForm" type="checkbox" value="1" <% if (ba.OLD_FORM.HasValue    && ba.OLD_FORM.Value) Response.Write (" checked "); %> />
<input name="hdnOldForm" id="hdnOldForm" type="hidden" value="<% if (ba.OLD_FORM.HasValue && ba.OLD_FORM.Value) Response.Write ("1"); %>" />
```

Here is my javascript:

```
 function testCheckbox() {
                $("#ButtonAdd").click (function(){
                    $("#Oldform").prop("checked", true);

                });
            }

            testCheckbox();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have you identifier misspelled in your jQuery expression.

```
$("#Oldform").prop("checked", true);
```

needs to be

```
$("#OldForm").prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: Thanks Lee - much appreciated. Can't believe I missed that.